# Please check my proof (that integral = 0 implies integrand = 0 a.e. in a Bochner space setting)

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

Let $V$ be Hilbert and separable. Suppose $f \in L^2(0,T;V')$.
I want to show that if
$$\langle f, v \rangle=0$$
holds for all $v \in L^2(0,T;V)$, then 
$$\langle f(t), w(t) \rangle_{V',V} = 0\quad\text{for almost every $t \in (0,T)$}$$
holds for all $w \in L^2(0,T;V)$.

---

Attempted proof:
Let $v \in L^2(0,T;V).$ Then
$$\langle f, v \rangle = \int_0^T \langle f(t), v(t) \rangle_{V',V}.$$
Now pick $v = \varphi w$, where $\varphi \in C_c^\infty(0,T)$ and $w \in L^2(0,T;V)$. Then the above becomes
$$\langle f, v \rangle = \int_0^T \varphi(t)\langle f(t), w(t) \rangle_{V',V}$$
which holds for all $w \in L^2(0,T;V)$ and for all $\varphi \in C_c^\infty(0,T)$. Then by a well-known result, we find
$$\langle f(t), w(t) \rangle_{V',V}=0 \quad\text{for almost every $t \in (0,T)$}$$
and for every $w \in L^2(0,T;V)$.

---

Is this right? I am not sure I can pick $v=\varphi w$ like that.. what if $w$ contains a term $\frac{1}{\varphi}?$

Comment: First, you have to correct your statement. What is $v$ in the conclusion?

Comment: @gerw I edited it. $v$ is just a dummy variable since it ranges over all of $L^2(0,T;V).$ Soit can be called $v$ or $w$. But anyway I changed my statement.

Comment: this is still not correct. Do you mean if $\langle f,v\rangle = 0$ for all $v$, then $\langle f(t), w(t) \rangle = 0$ holds a.e. for all $w$?

Comment: Sorry yes that is correct. I edited it again..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if I'm missing the point of the question:

First we identify $V'$ with $V$ and $L^2(0,T,V)$ with $L^2(0,T,V')$ via the Riesz Representation. Suppose that $\langle f, v \rangle = 0$ for all $v \in L^2(0,T,V)$. Then in particular
$$\int_0^T \! \|f(t)\|^2 \, dt = \langle f, f \rangle = 0$$
Hence $\|f(t)\| = 0$ and thus $f(t) = 0$ almost everywhere. Thus $\langle f(t), w(t) \rangle = 0$ almost everywhere for any $w \in L^2(0,T,V)$.

Comment: Thanks, let me think about this answer.